# support for varchar[] array type in R2DBC Postgres Criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-webflux, project-reactor, r2dbc

I am trying to build a query similar to the below query using **criteria** query having varchar[] column in Postgres.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE (arrays['value1','value2']::varchar[] && column_name)
```

But it appears that there is no out of the box support for **varchar[]** in R2dbcEntityTemplate.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I'm not sure if a specific stack requirement is present, or if third party libraries are an option. If they are, you could use [jOOQ's R2DBC support](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/reactive-fetching/) to handle the data type binding for you, a bit more transparently. With jOOQ, you'd write:

```java
Flux<TableNameRecord> flux =
Flux.from(
    ctx.selectFrom(TABLE_NAME)
       .where("{0} && {1}"), 
           DSL.val(new String[] { "value1", "value2" }),
           TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME
));
```

The above approach is using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to use the `&&` operator. The `DSL.val()` call creates an array bind variable, which produces a `$1::varchar[]` expression for you, behind the scenes, and correctly binds the array to the R2DBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would possibly be the case of using a converter? Please take a look to this link:

[Spring RD2DBC mapping](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/mapping.adoc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ivan. I have gone through the link but I am not able to figure out how exactly it is going to help in filtering the data. could you please help me understand. TIA

Comment: Looking at Lukas Eder response, I had a better understanding of your question, my bad.  Please take a look if JOOQ meets you needs. Thx

Comment: BTW, my link seems to be broken, wth... 